# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum issue

Tags: swift, uiimageview, swift2, uiimage, uikit

I am having an issue with an UIImage that fails to save using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum. I have:

- Pushed the image to an UIImageView and it works fine.
- Checked UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum's didFinishSavingWithError and get no error.
- Tried using a different UIImage on UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum and it works fine.

I am getting the problematic UIImage from the output of a complex class that applies some complex filters on it. What could be wrong with it?

Thanks.

Comment: UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum sucks. ALAssetsLibrary's                 writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum works fine.

Comment: Do you know any similar method to writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum in the new PHPhotoLibrary since ALAssetsLibrary deprecated in iOS 9? Thanks.